# Are these proofs on partial orders correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove whether the following are true or false for partial orders $P_1$ and $P_2$ over the same set $S$.

1) **$P_1$ ∪ $P_2$ is reflexive?**

True, since $P_1$ and $P_2$ contains all the pairs { ($x,x$) : $x$ in $S$}, we know the union also does. Thus $P_1$ ∪ $P_2$ is reflexive. That set of ($x,x$) elements is called Δ, or the diagonal of $S$.

2) **$P_1$ ∪ $P_2$ is transitive?**

False, since $x≤y$ and $y≤z$ in $P_1$ ∪ $P_2$. How do we know $x≤y$ is from $P_1 and $y≤z$ isn't from $P_2? There's nothing guaranteeing that we have $x≤z$.

3) **$P_1$ ∪ $P_2$ is antisymmetric?**

False, for all we know, $x≤y$ in $P_1$ and $y≤x$ in $P_2$. That would be the complete opposite of asymetry - symmetry (for those two elements, at least).

Comment: You have not specified where the elements x, y, and z belong to - what set do they belong to? try again

Comment: p.s. antisymmetry is if x <= y and y <= x, then x = y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not call (2) or (3) a satisfactory answer.

In order to show something is false, you can not do informal reasoning like "How do we know x≤y is from P1andy≤zisn′tfromP_2? There's nothing guaranteeing that we have x≤z." to show something is false.

You have to produce two actually partial orderings $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that $P_1 \cup P_2$ is not transitive.

For example, let $S = \{x, y, z\}$. Let $P_1 = \{(x,y), (x,x), (y,y), (z,z)\}$ and $P_2 = \{(y,z), (x,x), (y,y), (z,z)\}$. Then $(x,y) \in P_1 \cup P_2$ and $(y,z) \in P_1 \cup P_2$ but $(x,z) \notin P_1 \cup P_2$.

For anti-symmetry, again let $S = \{x,y,z\}$, where all these are three distinct elements. Let $P_1 = \{(x,y), (x,x), (y,y), (z,z)\}$ and $P_2 = \{(y,x), (x,x), (y,y), (z,z)\}$. Then $(x,y) \in P_1 \cup P_1$ and $(y, x) \in P_1 \cup P_2$ however $x$ and $y$ are two different elements.

Comment: For the anti-symmetry, did you mean to say that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are two different elements, not $x$ and $y$?

Comment: No it is how he has written it. We want to show that antisymmetry fails to hold, to show that in general it may not hold in the union of two partial orders. So, we have $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are both there so if antisymmetry were to hold then $x=y$ but $x$ and $y$ are distinct elements so antisymmetry doesn't hold so we can say then that we have an example of the union of two partial orders having antisymmetry not carrying to the union.

Answer (score 3):

Good proof of the first one, and your intuition seems to be spot on for the other two, if I'm understanding you correctly. However, you have not *proved* that a union of partial orders on the same set need not be transitive or antisymmetric.

To do so, you must provide *counterexamples*. In particular, demonstrate a set $S$ and partial orders $P_1$ and $P_2$ on $S$ such that $R:=P_1\cup P_2$ is not transitive (or antisymmetric, depending on which you're trying to disprove). You should be able to accomplish both with small finite sets.

P.S.: It seems that you *might* be confusing the definition of antisymmetry. To show that $R$ is not antisymmetric, you must find distinct $x,y\in S$ such that both $x\: R\: y$ and $y\: R\: x.$

Answer (score 2):

1) Your answer is correct.  One can just as easily say something stronger: if $R_1$ is a reflexive relation on a set $X$ and $R_2$ is any relation on $X$ containing $R_1$, then $R_2$ is also reflexive.

2) Your conclusion is correct, but you should nail it down by giving a specific counterexample.  Can you find one?  It suffices to take $X = \{1,2,3\}$.

3) To be sure, antisymmetric means that if $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$, then $x = y$.  Again your conclusion is correct but should be justified.  Here an easy example would be to take $P_1$ to be any linear order $\leq$ on a set with more than one element -- e.g. the standard ordering on $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ -- and $P_2$ to be the dual ordering, i.e., $x \leq_2 y \iff y \leq x$.  Then $P_1 \cup P_2$ is the total relation $x R y$ for all $x,y$.  This is not antisymmetric.